# Unpack zip file: “End-of-central-directory signature not found” error

Tags: command-line, unzip

I keep getting this error every time I try to unzip my file:

```
Archive:  Server.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of Server.zip or
        Server.zip.zip, and cannot find Server.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I've zipped it with 7zip but it still isn't working. I've read something about MD5, do I need that to unzip?

Comment: Read the error "Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive." . Where did you get the .zip from ? Run `file Server.zip` to see if it is a zip. If so, contact the person who made it.

Comment: It says this now.. so it isnt a ZIP file now that i know that. I've been using 7 Zip to zip my files should i use somthing else then? Its my server folder and i zipped it up with 7 zip

Comment: Sounds odd, you would have to post the commands you ran for help debugging. Personally I use tar more than zip, but zip should work.

Comment: Unpack it using 7z. If that does not work, it's likely corrupted, and you need to re-make it and re-transmit it. 7z may use exotic compression not supported by *all* zip sotware.

Answer (score 2):

I tested with `7z`, `zip` and `unzip` deliberately mixing the programs, but I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. However it that may very well be specific to the data which is compressed.
As `7z` uses the [7z format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z) by default and file name extensions don't matter I first thought it would create a 7z format file just *named* `zip`, but turns out it's not that user-unfriendly:
`7z a 1.zip 2` does create a proper `1.zip` file even without the `-t zip` option which specifies the format.
`7z a 1 2` however creates `1.7z` and `7z a -t zip 1 2` creates `1.zip` as expected.

In general it's a good idea to

1. use the **same program** to pack and to unpack an archive:

   ```bsh
   7z a Server.zip file1 file2 dir1/ # add files
   7z x Server.zip # extract with full paths
   7z e Server.zip # extract IGNORING paths
   ```

   ---

   ```bsh
   zip Server.zip file1 file2 dir1/ # add files
   unzip Server.zip # extract with full paths
   ```
2. use a **cryptographic hash** to test whether the archive got transferred correctly:

   1. On your server, save the hash sum with `md5sum`, `sha1sum`, `sha224sum`, `sha256sum`, `sha384sum` or `sha512sum`<sup>1</sup> (all following the same syntax), e.g.

      ```bsh
      sha1sum Server.zip otherfile.zip > sha1hashsums
      ```
   2. Transmit both the zip file(s) and the `sha1hashsums` file.
   3. Test the zip file(s) with e.g.

      ```bsh
      $ sha1sum -c sha1hashsums
      Server.zip: FAILED
      otherfile.zip: OK
      ```

<sup>1</sup> The most important difference   between them is the size of the hash, a longer hash being more secure. [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) produces a 128-bit hash, [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) a 160-bit one, [the others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) bear the hash sum size in their name, e.g. `sha512sum` for a 512-bit hash. I'll leave the rest to Wikipedia, see the links.